# How get continuity of $a(u,v)=\int_{\Omega }\nabla u\cdot \nabla v-\int_{B_2\backslash B_1}3^{-d}uv$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $u,v\in H^1(\Omega )$ where $\Omega =B_2\backslash B_1$. How can I have continuity and coercivity of
$$a(u,v)=\int_{\Omega }\nabla u\cdot \nabla v-\int_{B_2\backslash B_1}3^{-d}uv\ ?$$

The best thing I get is $$|a(u,v)|\leq \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}\|\nabla v\|_{L^2}+3^{-d}\|u\|_{L^2}\|v\|_{L^2},$$
but I can't get $|a(u,v)|\leq C\|u\|_{H^1}\|v\|_{H^1}$. And for coercivity, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\|u\|_{H^1}=\|u\|_{L^2}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$, therefore $\|u\|_{L^2},\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}\leq \|u\|_{H^1}$ and same for $v$. You can then conclude for continuity. For coercivity,
$$a(u,u)=\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2-3^{-d}\int_\Omega |u|^2\geq \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2-3^{-d}\int_\Omega |u|^2=\|u\|_{H^1}^2-(1+3^{-d})\int|u|^2\geq\|u\|_{H^1}^2.$$

For coercivity, I used the equivalent norm $\|u\|_{H^1}=\sqrt{\|u\|_{L^2}^2+\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2}$.

Comment: How do you obtain the last inequality? By plugging in the constant function $u = 1$, I find $a(u,u) = -3^-d \, |B_2 \setminus B_1| < 0$, contradicting coercivity of $a$.

Comment: @gerw: Indeed, I was to fast. I don't have time now, but feel free to make an answer, I'll erase mine and upvote yours if it's good.

Answer (score 0):

The bilinear form $a$ is not continuous. By plugging in the constant function $u = 1$, we find $a(u,u) = -3^{-d} \, |B_2 \setminus B_2| < 0$. Hence, $a$ cannot be coercive.